# How can I post a form using paypal subscription button? Or is there any way to post a form containing paypal content only?

Tags: asp.net, paypal

I am using PayPal subscription 
I have issue with paypal subscribe button. I have subscribe button with 4 subscription options. I want to add this selected option in query string. So that my query string will look like this:

```
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-lick&hosted_button_id=Y1TOJTYQ2ALDJ&os0=Silver Membership
```

In above query string I want to set selected option for os0 parameter.

My Code:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">

<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick"/>
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="X9TEPZ7Q2ALDJ"/>
<table>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Memberships">Memberships</td></tr><tr><td>
<select name="os0">
<option value="Registration - One month">Registration - One month : $1.00USD - monthly</option>
<option value="Trial Membership">Trial Membership : $25.00USD - monthly</option>
<option value="Silver Membership">Silver Membership : $250.00USD - yearly</option>
<option value="Gold Membership">Gold Membership : $400.00USD - yearly</option>
</select> 
</td></tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD"/>
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal — The safer, easier way to pay online."/>
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1"/>                            
<a id="paypalDonate" target="_blank" href ="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=Y1TOJTYQ2ALDJ&os0=document.getelementbyid(os0).value">

<img border="0" id="payPalImage" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif" alt="Donate to DevtheWeb.NET" />
</a>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by using ImageButton instead of anchor tag.

as below:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="payPalImage" ImageUrl="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif" runat="server" OnClick="payPalImage_Click" />
```

On click event of ImageButton, in back end file(.cs file), I attached selected subscription option like:

```
protected string _SubscriptionVal = "";

....
protected void payPalImage_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    _SubscriptionVal = Request["os0"];
    Response.Redirect("https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=X34EQZ8Q2AFASLDJ&os0="+_SubscriptionVal);
}
```

and finally I could able to redirect to paypal account with appropriate values.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. Either don't use dropdowns and use the email link PayPal gives you (which is basically the link you have, minus the option select), or use a `<form>` POST.
You cannot combine a dropdown selection with a link.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I used image button instead of anchor tag and in click event I build query string and redirect to pay pal.